# Storing objects to localStorage React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, local-storage, auth0

I have tried some things here.

1. Stringify user object and storing to localStorage. Get the user using JSON.parse()
2. Storing plain user object. Parsing user when getting.
3. etc.

All posibilities either return `[Object] object` or parse error. What is the correct way?

```js
import { useAuth0, withAuthenticationRequired } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
export const PrivateHome = ({ fetchUserMetaData, user_metadata }) => {
    const { user, getAccessTokenWithPopup } = useAuth0();
    if (!localStorage.getItem("user")) localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user, null, 2))
    return (
        <h1>Private Home</h1>
    )
}
```

```js
 const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
```

errpr

```js
index.js:1 Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
```

```
email: "gmail@gmail.com"
email_verified: true
family_name: "name"
given_name: "name"
locale: "en"
name: "name"
nickname: "nickname"
picture: "picture"
sub: "1231231231764132451235035"
updated_at: "2021-11-21T13:11:43.091Z"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: May you share an example `user` object?

Comment: Is `useAuth0` an async function?

Comment: `useAuth0` is a hook

Comment: don't store things in local storage in the main body of a function component. You should use `useEffect` for side effects like that (or do it in an event handler, depending on your business requirements). [Likely the same applies for `fetchUserMetadata()`, but it's not clear what that does.]

Comment: It could be that `user` is undefined when being set? `JSON.parse('undefined')` throws an error

Comment: @evolutionxbox no, I can log it to the console.

Comment: @RobinZigmond sorry `fetchUserMetadata()` was out of context

Comment: That sadly seeing it with `console.log` doesn't mean it's available at the time it's being set.

Comment: try removing `if (!localStorage.getItem("user"))` from code and then test it, maybe there is already dirty data in localStorage against 'user' key

Comment: @Abdur-RehmanM hmm, now getting new things.

Comment: @Abdur-RehmanM you solved it. Thanks.